# How to assign a format string to variable in GDB?

Tags: fortran, gdb

I am debugging fortran programs using GDB, and I'd like to write a gdb function to pretty print (format print) a 2D array.

The function needs format string like "%.4f" as an argument, but the command `set $format="%.4f"` is not correct due to `Invalid character '"' in expression.`

My questions are:

1.How to assign a format string to a variable?

2.Is it possible to judge the type of variable in the function so that it can use the correct format string automatically.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The current source language is "auto; currently fortran".